# Return a record with a maximum value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause

For context, I am practicing and using a table with a load of international footballing results. Table layout is as follows

Date, Home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score

I am attempting to filter the data to reveal the match which has Pakistan's highest ever home score.

I tried the following query

```
SELECT date, home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score
FROM `my-practice-project-394200.football_results.scores`
Where home_score = (select max (home_score)
                    FROM `my-practice-project-394200.football_results.scores`
                    Where home_team = "Pakistan")
```

However it returns many records for other countries as below

[Results of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkzu0.png)

I believe the logic being executed is that it takes Pakistan's highest every home score of 9 and returns any home scores where the home team scored at least 9

So just need to understand how to tighten it to filter to show Pakistan only

Comment: `where home_score = (...) and home_team = "Pakistan"`?

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the country condition in the outer query:

```
SELECT date, home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score
FROM `my-practice-project-394200.football_results.scores`
Where home_team = "Pakistan"
      and home_score = (select max (home_score)
                    FROM `my-practice-project-394200.football_results.scores`
                    Where home_team = "Pakistan")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at your query's `WHERE` clause, You will be able to understand what is the issue.

Your query in words:

```
Select ...
From ...
WHERE home_score = (Max score of Pakistan as a home team i.e. 9)
```

So Your query is returning you all the records where home_score is 9 without checking the country. Even though you have used the `home_country` condition, it is not enough.

Use the following:

```
SELECT date, home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score
FROM `my-practice-project-394200.football_results.scores`
Where home_score = (select max (home_score)
                    FROM `my-practice-project-394200.football_results.scores`
                    Where home_team = "Pakistan") 
  and home_team = "Pakistan"
```

Or You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT date, home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score
FROM `my-practice-project-394200.football_results.scores` t
Where not exists 
     (select 1 from `my-practice-project-394200.football_results.scores`
       where t.home_team = tt.home_team and tt.home_score > t.home_score)
 and home_team = "Pakistan"
```

Comment: This worked, adding home_team = "Pakistan" to the other side of the sub-query. Thanks